Using the functional derivative and delta function for proving The Fokker-Planck Equation
I am reading "Lectures on Phase Transitions" by Nigel Goldenfeld, specifically Chapter 8, where the Fokker-Planck equation is derived. I found the following part of the proof, but there are two steps that are not clear to me:
In the second line, I expect to find a delta function to type the integral over $r'$:
$ \int d^d r'\delta(r - r')  \left\langle \frac{\partial \bar{\eta}(r', t)}{\partial t} \frac{\delta}{\delta \bar{\eta}(r', t)} \delta[\eta(r') - \bar{\eta}(r', t, \{\zeta\})] \right\rangle_\zeta \\$
In the third line, it is not clear to me how to get the minus functional derivative in front. I tried to apply the product rule, but I did not get it right.
Here are the steps I am referring to:
\begin{align}
\partial_t P_n(\{\eta(r)\}, t) &= \left\langle \partial_t \delta[\eta(r) - \bar{\eta}(r, t, \{\zeta\})] \right\rangle_\zeta \\
&= \int d^d r' \left\langle \frac{\partial \bar{\eta}(r', t)}{\partial t} \frac{\delta}{\delta \bar{\eta}(r', t)} \delta[\eta(r) - \bar{\eta}(r, t, \{\zeta\})] \right\rangle_\zeta \\
&= -\int d^d r' \frac{\delta}{\delta \eta(r')} \left\langle \frac{\partial \bar{\eta}(r', t)}{\partial t} \delta[\eta - \bar{\eta}] \right\rangle_\zeta \\
&= -\int d^d r' \frac{\delta}{\delta \eta(r')} \left\langle \left[-\Gamma \frac{\delta L}{\delta \eta(r')} + \zeta(r', t) \right] \delta[\eta - \bar{\eta}] \right\rangle_\zeta \\
&= \int d^d r' \frac{\delta}{\delta \eta(r')} \left[ \Gamma P_n \frac{\delta L}{\delta \eta(r')} - \left\langle \zeta \delta[\eta - \bar{\eta}] \right\rangle_\zeta \right].
\end{align}
Here, $ζ$ is the noise term due to thermal fluctuations, and $$ is the field configuration.
The steps afterward are clear to me. Could someone explain how the delta function appears in the second equation and how the minus functional derivative is obtained in the third equation?

What do you mean "how the delta function appears in the second equation"? It was there in the first equation, so of course it's still there in the second? Or do you mean how $\partial_t$ turns into $\partial_t\bar{\eta}\cdot\partial_{\bar{\eta}}$?

@kyle
I updated my post accordingly. I mean that I expected:
$ \int d^d r'\delta(r - r')  \left\langle \frac{\partial \bar{\eta}(r', t)}{\partial t} \frac{\delta}{\delta \bar{\eta}(r', t)} \delta[\eta(r) - \bar{\eta}(r, t, {\zeta})] \right\rangle_\zeta \$.
I know that $ \partial_t $ turns into $ \partial_t\bar{\eta}\cdot\partial_{\bar{\eta}}
$ using chain rule.
